# Child Fragment's setUserVisibleHint and onResume not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, visibility

I am trying to call a function when user switch the page to my child fragment. But, when I try to use setUserVisibleHint and onResume, both functions are called from my parent fragment.

[image]

First, I set up a view pager in `Activity`

Then in A1, A3 and B1, I have setUserVisibleHint and onResume functions.

setUserVisibleHint and onResume functions

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
    Log.d("A1", "setUserVisibleHint"); // A3 for Fragment A3 and B1 for Fragment B1 
    if (visible && isResumed())
        onResume();
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("A1", "onResume"); // A3 for Fragment A3 and B1 for Fragment B1 
    if (!getUserVisibleHint())
        return;
}
```

Issues:

When I click page B from page A and the view is Fragment B1, I get (This is OK)

```
D/A1: setUserVisibleHint
D/B1: setUserVisibleHint
D/B1: onResume
```

When I click page A from page B and the view is Fragment A1, I get (This is OK)

```
D/B1: setUserVisibleHint
D/A1: setUserVisibleHint
D/A1: onResume
```

When I click page A from page B and the view is Fragment A3, I get (ISSUE)

```
D/B1: setUserVisibleHint
D/A1: setUserVisibleHint
D/A1: onResume
```

I assume that the printout should be like below but I am not sure why the functions called by parent fragment.

```
D/B1: setUserVisibleHint
D/A3: setUserVisibleHint
D/A3: onResume
```

Reference

From fragment A1 -> A2,

```
A2 a2 = new A2();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.A1_frameChildFragment, a2)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

From fragment A2 -> A3,

```
A3 a3 = new A3();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.A2_frameChildFragment, a3)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

Comment: Please share the code for where are you adding the fragment A2 and A3. Are you adding fragment A2 and A3 in Fragment A1??

Comment: Do not call lifecycle methods (such as onResume) yourself. They're controlled by Android, do not interfere, or you'll break something.

Answer (score 6):

`onResume` **will not called** when you switch between tab in `ViewPager`.
`setUserVisibleHint` **will called** in the parent fragment of each tab when you switch between in `ViewPager` and **will not called** in child fragment.
This is the default behavior so I think we can not change it.

However, there is a workaround solution. It is sending the visible hint from parent fragment to child fragment

```
// visible hint in parent fragment
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (!isAdded()) {
        return;
    }
    Fragment fragment = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.A1_frameChildFragment); // find current child fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser); // send visible from parent to this child fragment
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. !! Thanks for sharing ;)

Comment: It crashes that child Fragment is not attached yet

Answer (score 3):

setOnPageChangeListener method is now deprecated, use addOnPageChangeListener instead

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // do your work
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you have to call your fragment when you load / when you click on the tab bar/tab view.

Like in your case all fragments are load at the same time so when you change the fragment it not provide any event in class.

For my application, I got the same issue so I load the fragment when I click on the tab then after the fragment called and will provide the event.

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all always start or create a fragment from `Activity`. Because `Fragment` is basically a instance or a part of your Activity. That's why, always start or create fragment from `Activity` context instead of `Fragment` for better control over fragment lifecycle.

For example to start `FragmentA` from `FragmentB` create a method in your `Activity` as,

```
public void startFragmentB(){
   FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   FragmentB fragment = new FragmentB();
   FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
   transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack("tag");
   transaction.commit();
}
```

Now where you want to start or create `FragmentB` in your `FragmentA` just call above method from your activity as,

```
((YourActivity) getActivity()).startFragmentB();
```

Comment: This is not a good solution for child fragments. One often wants to receive calls to `onAttachFragment(Fragment)` in the parent fragment when the child is attached to the activity. With this proposal, that call-back won't happen. Better to install the child fragment by using `getChildFragmentManager()` directly in the parent fragment, not the activity.